# spring CallableStatement with named parameter

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, plsql

When i try to set my input with parameterIndex(setInt(1,id)) it works perfectly.but when i try to id with parametername(like below code) it returns null values and i dont understand why. anyone can help?

My procedure is:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE2 (
   i_emp_no IN INT  default 1234,
   o_emp_name OUT VARCHAR2,
   out_sal OUT INT)
AS

BEGIN
  o_emp_name := NULL;
  out_sal := NULL;

  SELECT ENAME,SAL 
  INTO o_emp_name, out_sal  
  FROM EMP 
  WHERE EMPNO = i_emp_no;

END PROCEDURE2;
```

My calling method from spring is:

```
public ResponseModel testProcedure(int id) throws SQLException{

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

    String procedureCallString = "{call PROCEDURE2(?,?,?)}";
    ResponseModel response = new ResponseModel();

    try {           
        if(dataSource == null){
            logger.debug("dataSource is null");
            return response;
        }

        dbConnection = dataSource.getConnection();
        callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(procedureCallString);

        callableStatement.setInt("i_emp_no", id);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

        boolean isResultSet = callableStatement.execute();

        if ( isResultSet ){             
            logger.debug("returned resultset");

        }else{
            logger.debug("NOT returned resultset");             
        }

        response.setName(callableStatement.getString(2));
        response.setAddress("address");
        response.setHeight(callableStatement.getInt(3));

        //System.out.println("enmp name : " + userName);
        //System.out.println("sal : " + sal);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }finally {

        if (callableStatement != null) {
            callableStatement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }

    return response;        
}
```

Comment: create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE2 ( i_emp_no IN INT default 1234, o_emp_name OUT VARCHAR2, out_sal OUT INT )   .. I dont understand the OUT parameter as INT . Is this procedure working?

Comment: Have you tried all words in UPPERCASE?

Comment: yes after trying all variables with upper letters i solved problem.  response.setName(callableStatement.getString(2));
        i get item also with name(getString(paramName) it worked.